# Cannot run phpunit test, failed opening required class

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

So, here is the strucuture of my project

```
project_name
  /classes
      Calculator.php
  /test
      CalculatorTest.php
  /vendor
      // Related composer/phpunit etc ... stuff
  composer.json
  composer.lock
```

**Calculator.php**

```
<?php
class Calculator{
    public function double($input){
        return $input * 2; 
    }
}
```

**CalculatorTest.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../classes/Calculator.php'; 

class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    public $testClass; 

    public function setUp(){
        $testClass = new Calculator; 
    }

    public function testDouble(){
        $result = $testClass->double(2); 
        $this->assertEquals(4, $result);        
    }

}
```

When I run *phpunit ../../test*, I get the following error:

> Warning: require_once(../classes/Calculator.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\phpunit\test\CalculatorTest.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error:
>   require_once(): Failed opening required '../classes/Calculator.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\phpunit\test\CalculatorTest.php on line 3

I can't find a fix. Do you have any idea?

**EDIT** 
Got, it, forget the **spl_autoload_register** within the tests classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php'; 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the file in a different page. So the path is incorrect.

try this:

```
 require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/Calculator.php
```

And if Calculator is in the same folder as classes as calculator test than you dont need to set the path /classes

Comment: You are opening C:\wamp\www\phpunit\test\CalculatorTest.php and you set the path as require_once '../classes/Calculator.php'; that means you're going outside the test folder ( ../ ) and i think that your folder classes is inside the test folder. try it without ../ so require_once 'classes/Calculator.php';

Comment: It works! But I can assure you that my classes folder is not in my tests folder...